# Reactjs How to pass the props of current page into child page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is `Clients_info.js`

In this component's props, it has several values.

And now I want to pass all the `props` in this component to the `Modalbox` component.

I know how to pass value from the current `state` to child component in render function as `props`. But....from `props` to `props`...

How could I make that? Thanks!

```js
import React from "react";

import Modalbox from './Client_modal'

require('../../css/Clients.scss');

var $ = require ('jquery');

export default class Clients_info extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  //Invoked once, both on the client and server, immediately before the initial rendering occurs.
  componentWillMount(){

  }


  render() {
    return(
      <div id='tabbox-order' className='clients_info'>
        <div id='clientsInfo_wrapper'>
          <div id='clientsInfo_row'>
            <div id='ava_wrapper'>
              <img id='clietnsInfo_avatar'></img>
              <p>{this.props.client.name}</p>
            </div>

            <div id='infor_wrapper'>
              <p><i class="material-icons">email</i> Email: {this.props.client.email}</p>
              <p><i class="material-icons">phone</i> Phone: {this.props.client.phone}</p>
              <p><i class="material-icons">location_on</i> Address: {this.props.client.loc}</p>
              <p><i class="material-icons">my_location</i> Zip Code: {this.props.client.zip}</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id='key' >
            <i  class="material-icons">vpn_key</i>{this.props.client.key}
          </div>
          <div id='Cutting' ></div>
          <div>
            <h4>Pets Information</h4>
            { this.props.pets.map(function(pet) {
                  return(
                    <div>
                      <div className='row'key={pet.id}>
                        <div className='col-md-3' >avatar</div>
                        <div className='col-md-3' >{pet.petName}</div>
                        <div className='col-md-3' >{pet.breed}</div>
                        <div className='col-md-3' >{pet.age}</div>
                      </div>

                      <div id='pet-detail'>
                        <p>Extra Information:</p>
                        <input placeholder='This dog is crazy!!!'>
                        </input>

                      </div>
                    </div>

                  )
              })
            }

          </div>

          <div id='Cutting' ></div>

          <Modalbox/>

        </div>



      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: passing state as props, or props as props is identical

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So does that means I could do like this `<Modalbox info={this.props.client.name}/>` ?

Comment: yup! that's all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Modalbox pets={ this.props.pets }/>
```

Should do the job